# CMD bat file: how to run PowerShell script with Start-Process command without writing to disk?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm currently doing the following: I have a .bat file that I can just run by double clicking on it. It creates another bat file with a command and after that it runs with `powershell -command "Start-Process elevated.ps1 -Verb runas"` to ask for administrator privileges for that script. 
My .bat file looks like the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
Rem Write the command to file and run as elevated
echo powershell -nop -c "iex(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/xyz/somescript.ps1')" > elevated.ps1
powershell -command "Start-Process elevated.ps1 -Verb runas"
```

I want to skip the part that writes to the disk so basically I want to run the command that downloads the other script and runs it. 
I'm looking for something like the following:

```
powershell -command "Start-Process 'the long command here somehow' -Verb runas"
```

Comment: if you want to change from non-elevated to elevated ... then you MUST start a new process. however, you should be able to do that in one step by converting the long command to something like a base64 encoded string.

Comment: This all sounds kind of nefarious to me.  ;-} If your risk management/security policy team, and saw this, caught this in and audit, risk check, well, you know... ['invoke-expression is evil'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27invoke-expression+is+evil%27&t=h_&ia=web), this is why most risk-averse enterprises/orgs have policies block it altogether. [Lee Daily is is valid on the encode string approach](https://www.nextofwindows.com/powershell-fun-watch-rick-astley-sing-and-dance-never-let-you-down), but most orgs will block this because it's a default thing hackers do in PowerShell attacks.

Comment: @postanote The only reason that I'm using iex is because this script is meant to be run on clean install of Windows 10 by an "average end user" and it does some configurations on the computer without having the user to set the execution policy first through powershell. Also It's easy to change the actual script by just dropping a new file to amazon and it does not need user intervention. User should be able to just double click on the bat file.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey could you provide an example of encoding and passing the encoded string to the runas?

Comment: @Theamateurprogrammer - here you go [*grin*] ... PowerTip: Encode String and Execute with PowerShell | Scripting Blog — https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-encode-string-and-execute-with-powershell/